# SignalR connected callback not firing

Tags: signalr

I'm trying signalR 1.1.0 in MVC3 application. I've overriden OnConnected method as below:

```
    public class MyHub : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub
{

    public static List<string> Connections = new List<string>();
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    {
        Connections.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

And in Js, I've following:

```
  $(function () {
    $.connection.hub.start();
    $.connection.myHub.client.connected = function() {
         alert(1);
    };
   });
```

When I load my page, OnConnected on server does get hit in debug mode but the JS callback "alert(1)" never executes. There is no JS error on browser. Where am I going wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the hubs before calling start:

```
$(function () {
    $.connection.myHub.client.something = function() {

    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
        alert('I'm connected!');
    });
}
```

Check out the documentation for the javascript API:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: I thought connected is automatically invoked and is a part of library. Thanks for the support.

Comment: It is, if you're connected to the hub. When you have no client side callbacks you're not "connected"